# How to delete sections of path in GIMP?

Tags: inkscape, gimp, svg, path

I have a path in GIMP, imported from an SVG created in Inkscape. The path consists of multiple letters converted from text, so there are multiple unconnected sections of the path. I want to delete all of the letters except for one. What is the best way to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the text is all one combined path, you can delete nodes using the Paths Tool by holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+click to delete them. Continue deleting until the letter is completely gone. You can also delete line segments using the same method by doing this on a line rather than a node, but the nodes will be left behind.

If the paths for each letter are separate, you can delete a path in the Paths panel. Simply select the Path in the panel by highlighting it, and hit the X at the bottom of the palette to *Delete This Path*.

In the long run it might be easier to just edit the SVG in Inkscape, select all the paths you don't want, delete them, then save a new SVG and import that into GIMP.  Remember that GIMP isn't a vector image editor and only has very basic vector path support.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`ofn-path-edit`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-path-tools/files/scripts/) script, several ways:

- #1: Make a selection (Freehand, rectangle...) around the characters you want to delete (or keep) and use the `Delete Stroke/Extract strokes` function.
- #2: Use the `Break text path apart` function, that will create a new path per character (or diacritic mark). Keep the one you need.